# Serving service from kfserving github examples created with kubectl, but can not infere

Tags: kubernetes, pytorch, minikube, kubeflow, serving

I have installed minikube cluster and kfserving on a linux desktop.
Then I have followed two tutorials 
https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/tree/master/docs/samples/v1beta1/custom/torchserve 
https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/tree/master/docs/samples/v1alpha2/custom/kfserving-custom-model

In the second tutorial I have needed to move "name: custom" from "custom:" section to "container:" section in the yaml file. 
I expected that serving service was working and responding to serving requests and pods of the service where in kubernetes.  
I use the newest stable versions from May 2021.

But I have same bug in both tutorials. Bellow commands are from the first tutorial. When I prepare docker images with models and run

```
$ kubectl apply -f torchserve-custom.yaml
```

command.  
I see output like

```
inferenceservice.serving.kubeflow.org/torchserve-custom created
```

But I can not run a prediction, because service I get 404 not found. 
When I run

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

I do not see any new pods. 
But I can deleted service with

```
 $ kubectl delete -f torchserve-custom
```

When I have followed other tutorials like: https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/tree/master/docs/samples/v1beta1/torchserve everything worked fine and I could run predictions.

Why can`t I run a prediction?

Why any new pods are created?

How to setup serving in kfserving using docker image, if the above tutorials did not worked?

Comment: Have you checked if [KFServing](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/#test-kfserving-installation) is working properly ?

Comment: It turned out that my local docker registry wasn't visible from kubernetes. `kubectl get events` shows InternalError "Unable to fetch image ... "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my local docker registry wasn't visible from kubernetes. `kubectl get events` shows InternalError "Unable to fetch image ... "